# Can't permanently export PATH variable with custom path

Tags: 14.04, command-line, composer, laravel

I've installed `composer` and the `laravel` installer which is now located unter `~/.config/composer/vendor/bin`. I want to use `laravel` directly as a command from anywhere, so I tried to add the directory to the `$PATH` variable. I probably could create a symlink for the installer to `/usr/local/bin` but I still don't know why I can't set it permanently. I tried multiple ways

- `export PATH=$PATH:~/.config/composer/vendor/bin`
- Adding it to `~/.profile` like above and without the `export` statement and the value in quotes
- Adding it to `~/.bashrc` like above and without the `export` statement and the value in quotes
- Adding it to `/etc/environment` like `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:~/.config/composer/vendor/bin"`

After doing all of that (for 2 & 3 I even did `source`) it worked for the current session, but as soon as I closed the `Terminal` and reopened it the output would always be:

```
tzfrs@ubuntu:~$ laravel
laravel: command not found
```

I don't have any `bash_login` or `bash_profile` file in my home directory.

Comment: I believe your path statement would need to be the full folder name:  `/home/username/.config/composer/vendor/bin`

Comment: Added it like this to `~/.profile` and `/etc/environment` but no luck

Comment: When you change `/etc/environment` I believe you need to reboot for the global changes to take effect.

Comment: I'll report back

Comment: @Terrance - I'm using a VM, so will take 2-3 minutes.

Comment: It worked after rebooting. If you add your answer I will accept it since you provided the information with the reboot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the full directory in the `/etc/environment` for the PATH statement.

```
/home/username/.config/composer/vendor/bin
```

After the changes made, you need to reboot the host so that the changes in `/etc/environment` can take effect.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, since he provided the information with the reboot first.

Answer (score 5):

- `export PATH=$PATH:~/.config/composer/vendor/bin` works for the current session only.
- In `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` the `~/` doesn't get works within quotes, Either omit the quotes or use `$HOME` instead of `~/`, e.g.

  ```
  export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin
  ```
- `/etc/environment` doesn't allow any shell syntax so neither `~/` nor `$HOME` works. Instead you need to use the full path, e.g.

  ```
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/youruser/.config/composer/vendor/bin"
  ```

Comment: Hi. I modified my `/etc/environment` but still no luck. It looks like this: `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/tzfrs/.config/composer/vendor/bin"
`

Comment: @Musterknabe: `/etc/environment` is only read by `pam_environment` at login time. So you need to log out and log in again to make it work.

Comment: Hey. Yeah, that was it. But Terrance provided that info first so I accepted his answer. But I upvoted yours. Thanks for the tip with the `/etc/environment/`.